# Map instead of Set for relationship in Neo4j OGM

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In the [Neo4j OGM tutorial](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/), I see that only Set have been used for mapping relationships. Is it possible to use a map ?

Consider the following example

Suppose I have a class as follows:

```
 @NodeEntity
    public class Person {
     @Property
       String idCardNumber;

        Map <String, Car> cars;
    }

    @NodeEntity
    public class Car{
      @Id
       String plateNumber;
        @Property
       String color;
    }
```

**How to define a relationship from the class Person and Car given the it's a map that is being used in the class Person ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @meistermeier, this is not directly possible. But I uses a hack as in my case what i only need is to be able to persist the object directly in the database using Neo4j OGM. In short, i use a `set` and put the objects in it just before persisting the an instance of class `Person`. The codes are available below:

```
@NodeEntity
    public class Person {
     @Property
       String idCardNumber;

        @Transient
        Map <String, Car> cars;

        @Relationship(type = "hasCar",direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
        Set <Car> finalCars;

        public void beforeSave(){
                 finalCars = new HashSet<>(cars.values());
         }
    }

    @NodeEntity
    public class Car{
      @Id
       String plateNumber;
        @Property
       String color;
    }
```

Then, just before saving the `Person` object in the database, the cars are loaded in the set `finalCars`. This can be done directly in the method responsible for persisting a `Person` by calling `beforeSave()` on the insatance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because there is no way to store the additional information (e.g. the `String` in your example) in the database.
I would argue that there is no need for a `Map` structure for relationships at all because they are always defined by their type or the rich relationship entity via `@RelationshipEntity`.